# Send a Subscription email, verify if user clicked in "Confirm Subscription" and send an email if he clicked... in same function

Tags: python

I have this function below and in this function Im trying to  do 4 things:

-> create a topic

-> send a Confirm Subscription Email

-> verify if user clicked in "Confirm subscription"

-> send an email if user clicked in "Confirm Subscription"

The problem here is that, Im always getting the message "Pending Confirmation, please confirm subscription in you email and then we will sent you an email...".

Even when I confirm the subscription Im always getting this message, and I need to execute the code again to send the email.

But my idea was to send email without execute the code again, so I have a while loop to check the subscription status and when its diferent than "PendingConfirmation" I want to send the email that is this line:

`publication = c.publish(topicArnResult, message, subject=message_subject`

```
def createTopicSendConfirmSubscriptionSendEmail(msg):

    # here i get topic name and email from my msg dictonary
    topicname = msg['topico']

    emailaddress = msg['email']

    # I create a topic
    topicarn = c.create_topic(topicname)
    # And send a "Subscription Confirmation" email 
    # so the user can click in "Confirm Subscription" to start receive emails
    subscription = c.subscribe(topicArnResult, "email", emailaddress)

    # And then I want to send a email to the user, 
    # but only when he clicks in "Confirm subscription" link 
    # in the email sent in previous line


    getSubscriptions = c.get_all_subscriptions_by_topic(topicArn)
    # here i get the subscription email status
    getSubscriptionEmailStatus = getSubscriptions[...] 
    message = "test message"
    message_subject = "test subject"

    # while SubscriptionEmailStatus is "PendingConfirmation" I wan to show a message
    while getSubscriptionEmailStatus == "PendingConfirmation":      
        raw_input("Pending Confirmation, 
        please confirm subscription in your email
        and then we will sent you an email...")
        # here i get the subscription email status
        getSubscriptionEmailStatus = getSubscriptions[...] 

    # here I send an email but just when the status != "PendingConfirmation"    
    publication = c.publish(topicArnResult, message, subject=message_subject)
```

I tried to explain the issue in the best way but maybe is a bit confused, if you dont understand please say.

Comment: Where is the status chaged to a different value than `PendingConfirmation`?

Comment: if this where to run until user clicks confirmation, what do you do if user needs a few hours, a day, or even longer to click confirmation link? sure you could say it is only valid n minutes, but still you would have this process running for n users for n minutes... your server could run into severe problems... it is better practice to separate these tasks into two functions, so your server does nothing until the link was click and not one task waiting in a while loop which will cost memory and cpu time

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The status is changed to a different value inside the while loop, but even when I click in email link "Confirm subscription" the status just changes second time I execute the code! And that is the problem.

Comment: I understand your point, but the problem is that first email "Subscription Email" is sending by amazon sns, I dont know how I can execute a function after the user clicks in that link...So i thought in have that raw_input and check status until user clicks in "confirm subscription".

Comment: How does `raw_input` get email status, which must be determined based on activities performed on a different computer and, as @hexereisoftware rightly points out, could take a long (possibly infinite) amount of time?

Comment: Its not the raw_input that get status. Im trying to do that inside while loop wth getSubscriptionEmailStatus variable. And Im doing this just for testing purposes, so I want to show the message "Pending, confirmation...." and if I click enter and I have not yet clicked the email link I want show the message again, but if I already clicked in the email link I dont want to show the message and I want to execute the line publication = ... (that sends an email)